# Receiving error code 126 from my launchd job

Tags: ios, bash, scripting, permissions, launchd

I'm in the trying to learn a bit more about launchd and how I can use it to automate some tasks. For some reason when my **very simple** example job runs it exits with status code 126. I have changed permissions on all of my files to ensure I wasn't the issue (as 126 codes usually have something to do with permissions), but the issue persists.

/Library/LaunchDaemons/test.plst

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test.monday</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/philliptroutman/Desktop/test.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>20</integer>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

/Users/philliptroutman/Desktop/test.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
echo 'some data' >> /Users/philliptroutman/Desktop/examplefile.txt
echo "some random echo!"
```

After I load and unload the plst file this is what I get

```
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/test.plist
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/test.plist
launchctl list | grep test.monday
-   126 test.monday
```

I guess my question is very simple... why isn't this working?

Comment: I have created the same setup and it's working fine on my system. Add execute permission to test.sh.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this works with other machines @ParagBafna. I just confirmed and I have test.sh execute permissions set. Still receiving the same 126 code 

Comment: Update: never could figure out what was going on here. I ended up refactoring the project to run a node script instead of a bash script and everything worked as expected. ‍♂️

Comment: I also have the same problem...

Comment: Hi! I'm receiving the same problem too. With my shell script being simple writing to file... I've added execute permissions to the shell script... But I'm still receiving the same 126.. anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem with launchd plists that executed from my ~/Documents/scipts folder. The odd think is, they ran fine from a Google Drive folder Documents were linked to but on machines that just had my regular ~/Documents/scripts, they'd fail with error 126. Apple has designated ~/Documents Desktop and Downloads as private directories. Launchd cannot execute scripts from them.

Move the scripts do a different directory like ~/Library/scripts
You can always softlink them back to wherever you expected to find them.

Comment: That was the problem in my case. Thank you!

Comment: That was the problem in my case too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with launchd plists.
Different from what Matthew said, my solution is to use `/usr/local/bin/bash` to invoke the script rather than `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`.
The `/usr/local` one was installed by homebrew.
This surprisingly solved my problem.